# In NAnt <exec>, how to have a conditional <arg> based on property value?

Tags: nant

I've got an NAnt `<exec>` task. I want one argument presence to be conditional to some property being `true`.

For example, I want the `-c` command line argument of psExec to be conditional. It should be outputted only if `${pExec.copyprog == 'true'}`.

The following does not work:

```
<property name="psExec.copyprog" value="false" />
...

<exec program="${psExec.path}" failonerror="false">
   ...
   <arg line="-c" if="${psExec.copyprog}==true" />
</exec>
```

It yields the following error:

```
'false==true' is not a valid value for attribute 'if' of <arg ... />.
    Cannot resolve 'false==true' to boolean value.
       String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Properties in NAnt are tricky since they don't have a type and simply are considered as of type `string`. So this would be the solution:

```
<exec program="${psExec.path}" failonerror="false">
  <!-- ... -->
  <arg line="-c" if="${bool::parse(psExec.copyprog)}" />
</exec>
```

**Update:** Mea culpa! I was wrong. `if="${psExec.copyprog}"` does also work. So there is some sort of property typing.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to put `==true` inside `{}`, but you can also just skip it:

```
<arg line="-c" if="${psExec.copyprog}" />
```

Comparing a `true` boolean expression to `true` does not change the result.